# Compare two arrays containing "/" and keep common elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to compare two arrays that contain elements with "/" which means "or". The resulting Array_3 should compose of Array_1 elements that are in Array_2.

```
Array_1 = ["A", "B", "C/D"]

Array_2 = ["B/Z", "C/D/E"]
```

Array_3 for the above case should be [B, C/D] because B is part of B/Z (B or Z) and C/D (C or D) is part of C/D/E (C or D or E).

Array_3 = Array_1 & Array_2 would obviously not work in this case. Also, .split ("/") would not work since elements with "/" would be broken up - I would like to keep the original elements with "/".

Comment: These are not valid ruby arrays. What __exactly__ do you have?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! They are all string values. edited @SergioTulentsev

Comment: If `Array_1` had `"C/F"`, what should `Array_3` contain?

Comment: @MarkThomas In that case, Array_3 should include "C/F" as is because "C/D" (C or D) is part of "C/D/E" (C or D or E) - "C" is the common element.

Answer (score 2):

You could split `Array_2` strings and put them in a set. You just need to iterate over each element of `Array_1`, looking if there's any string included in `set_2`:

```
Array_1 = ["A", "B", "C/D"]
Array_2 = ["B/Z", "C/D/E"]

require 'set'

set_2 = Array_2.flat_map { |s| s.split('/') }.to_set
# <Set: {"B", "Z", "C", "D", "E"}>

p Array_1.select { |s| s.split('/').any? { |letter| set_2.include?(letter) } }
# ["B", "C/D"]
```

A [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is used simply because [`Set#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F) is much faster than [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), and `include?` is used multiple times.

Comment: without `to_set` getting same result, so what is the purpose of using `set`

Comment: @GaganGami: `Set#include?` is much faster (O(1)) than `Array#include?` (O(n)). If I have to call `include?` multiple times, I generally prefer the `set` variant. You're right though, the array variant would also work.

Comment: Yeah but `to_set` is (O(n)). Best is to create a Set to begin with and not resort to converting an Array to a Set (unless you will be doing lookups far more often than the conversion)

Comment: @MarkThomas: `to_set` is O(n) but it's called only once. `Array#include?` is O(n) every single time. If `Array_1` has `m` elements and `Array_2` has `n` elements, that's the difference between O(m+n) and O(m*n). Building a set directly wouldn't change the algorithmic complexity, it would add a few more lines though.

Comment: @EricDuminil : thanks man for well description, I was not knowing this deeply 1+ for this

Comment: I see what you're saying. And for large arrays it might actually make a detectable difference :)